# pipenv install failing due to timeout

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, pipenv

```
C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework>pipenv install --python 3.5
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework\Pipfile
Using C:\Users\danie01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe (3.5.0) to create virtualenv...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\expect.py", line 109, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout()
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\expect.py", line 82, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x05020630>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\danie01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli.py", line 435, in install
    selective_upgrade=selective_upgrade,
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1759, in do_install
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 609, in ensure_project
    three=three, python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 556, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 934, in do_create_virtualenv
    click.echo(crayons.blue(c.out), err=True)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\delegator.py", line 99, in out
    self.__out = self._pexpect_out
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\delegator.py", line 87, in _pexpect_out
    result += self.subprocess.read()
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 441, in read
    self.expect(self.delimiter)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 341, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\spawnbase.py", line 369, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\expect.py", line 119, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "c:\users\danie01\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pexpect\expect.py", line 82, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x05020630>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x05020630>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF
```

It seems like the issue might be that I want it to install the pipenv with python 3.5, but it's using python 3.6? I have both installed and in PATH. I'm not sure why an installer would be timing out.

I had previously installed a pipenv with 3.6 and removed it with some difficulty (I had to manually delete the virutalenv), so that may be part of the cause.

EDIT:

On a second attempt, it just hangs forever at `Using C:\Users\danie01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe (3.5.0) to create virtualenv...`

Answer (score 11):

`pipenv` ran a subprocess, and that process took longer than the default 15 minutes, then `expect.py` was told to wait for a newline but it hit the timeout and here you are.  First step is to increasing the TIMEOUT value in:

```
PIPENV_TIMEOUT
```

https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#configuration-with-environment-variables

```
PIPENV_INSTALL_TIMEOUT
    Max number of seconds to wait for package installation.
    Defaults to 900 (15 minutes), a very long arbitrary time.
```

If it's hanging forever, then the question becomes: What was pipenv told to do that results in a block?  Use the `--verbose` flag to tell pipenv to tell you what it's doing that results in a hang.

```
#try
export PIPENV_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=9000
```

Answer (score 8):

This helped me when installing on Raspberry Pi 3B+ on Raspbian.

```
# if actual install steps fail (installing X/X .. )
# default 900 seconds, 15 minutes, long time
export PIPENV_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=9999

# if creation of virtual env fails (very first step, first time)
# default 120 seconds, 2 minutes, not so long
export PIPENV_TIMEOUT=999

pipenv install requests
```

See https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#configuration-with-environment-variables for full definition of both values.

Comment: Setting both PIPENV_TIMEOUT and PIPENV_INSTALL_TIMEOUT to 9999 did the trick for me (https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#configuration-with-environment-variables).

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, turning off Windows Defender worked for me. I experienced no timeouts and the installations were much faster.

Comment: For Windows 10, I searched and opened "Windows Defender", clicked on "Firewall and network protection", a Public network connection was active so I clicked "Public network", then turned "Windows Defender firewall" to off.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you're running the `pipenv install` command, set env variable `PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR` to `off`. In my case, I set this in my Dockerfile by having a line `ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=false` before `RUN pipenv install`

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete your old virtualenv `C:\Users\danie01\.virtualenvs`

Check the version of python inside Pipfile

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.5"
```

After go to your project to create again your virtualenv

```
cd C:\Users\danie01\fox\test\robotframework
pipenv install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `url = "https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple"`, and for each dependence installed, I would have a timeout error. When I changed the url to simple worked.

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing `pipenv --rm` - removes virtual environment

then `pipenv shell` - this will again initiate virtual env

then `pipenv install` again

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `python3.5 -m pip install torch==1.6.0` (change to the python version you have and the package you need) after entering the environment with `pipenv shell`, especially if you have slow internet connection, because

- pipenv doesn't show the progress of downloading the package but pip does
- pipenv stops downloading a package after a certain time and outputs an error message but pip doesn't and waits for the package to download