# Pipenv on Windows: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, windows, pipenv, pipfile

I'm having trouble using Pipenv on my Windows 10 machine. Initially, I got a timeout error while trying to run `pipenv install <module>` and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509038/5535114), I disabled Windows Defender.

That got rid of the timeout error and it then seems to successfully install the package at **~/.virtualenvs** but I get an error when it comes to creating **Pipfile.lock**:

```
Adding flask to Pipfile's [packages]...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
File "C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 402, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir
File "C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 250, in actually_resolve_deps
    req = Requirement.from_line(dep)
File "C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\requirementslib\models\requirements.py", line 704, in from_line
    line, extras = _strip_extras(line)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've tried installing `requests` and `flask`, with the same results.

- **python**: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- **pip**: pip 18.0 from c:\users\edgar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
- **pipenv**: pipenv, version 2018.7.1

Any clues as to what is the problem/solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally solved it. This is current issue, with a [workaround](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924#issuecomment-427383459) for Windows:

`pipenv run python -m pip install -U pip==18.0`

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to update your pipenv version by using

```
>>> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

`>>> pip install --upgrade pipenv`

And then try to install your module again

```
>>> pipenv install <module_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem . It looks like problem happen with pip18.1 . However, you are using pip 18.0 . By the way, 
I solved by these commands . You can try it.

`pipenv run pip install pip==18.0
pipenv install`

Reference: 
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924

Comment: This didn't work for me, but someone posted a workaround for Windows under the same issue.