# Why does my pip install requests giving me an error when i install it?

Tags: python, python-requests, helper

I tried installing requests with "pip install requests" but it shows this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am on windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipenv on Windows: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711988/pipenv-on-windows-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may happens because you don't have proper set PATH of pip in your current machine, instead of use `pip install ...` you need to specify the python (may vary depending of your python version `python3` or `python`) path and add the `-m` flag to specify the module that you want to use.  in this case `pip`

try

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Comment: You may add more description why he meet that problem. Not only submitting a way to solve that. People may still have their confusion after getting your way tried.